# Access 2003 Database form query

Tags: microsoft-access-2003

I have a real headache (for me anyway). I have created an Access 2003 database with one master table and several linked tables for combo boxes. Here is my dilemma. The form created from the Master table displays some patient data, but the clinician needs to click on a button to add information re their cardio or respiratory status. The query needs to be displayed as a form which I have done, but the clinician is then required to re-enter the hospital number to get the patient related details to enter other information. This works to a point but is there a way of the clinician just clicking on a button that opens the form related to the current patient. Thanks. Ed

Answer (score 0):

In form editor, make sure the wizard is enabled (next to the pointer box),

[image]

and click the button thing, then click where you want it, the wizard will open and ask you want you want to do.

[image]

Select Form Operations, then Open Form. ... and select the form you want to open.